# Drag-drop not working in nhaarman's ListviewAnimation library

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-animation

I am using nhaarman's ListviewAnimation library https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations which works great.

But I am facing following issues:

The main problem I am facing is, I am not able to debug my code. I have directly copy/pasted the four required libraries into `libs` folder. Placing a debug point inside any of the listview methods like `onItemLongClick()` does not work.

The second problem is, drag-drop listView is not working in my code. Whenever I try to drag any list item, on dropping the list item, the item takes the same position from which it was dragged.

Here's the code I have used:

```
listview.enableDragAndDrop();
listview.setDraggableManager(new TouchViewDraggableManager(
        R.id.list_row_draganddrop_textview));
listview.setOnItemMovedListener(this);
listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);

@Override
    public void onItemMoved(final int originalPosition, final int newPosition) {
        if (mToast != null) {
            mToast.cancel();
        }

        mToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Moved"
                + swingBottomInAnimationAdapter.getItem(newPosition)
                + newPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        mToast.show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> parent,
            final View view, final int position, final long id) {
        if (listview != null) {
            listview.startDragging(position - listview.getHeaderViewsCount());
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

> Whenever I try to drag any list item, on dropping the list item, the item takes the same position from which it was dragged.

Of course. Handling the change in position is your responsibility, and you should take care of it inside the `onItemMoved` callback:

```
@Override
public void onItemMoved(final int originalPosition, final int newPosition) {
    if (mToast != null) {
        mToast.cancel();
    }

    mToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Moved"
            + swingBottomInAnimationAdapter.getItem(newPosition)
            + newPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    mToast.show();

    // Adapt the following to your implementation

    if (originalPosition != newPosition) {
            YourObject item = (YourObject) yourAdapter.getItem(originalPosition);
            yourAdapter.moveItem(item, newPosition);
    }
}
```

The method mentioned above would look something like:

```
public void moveItem(YourObject item, int newIndex) {
    if (mEntries != null) {
        mEntries.remove(item);
        mEntries.add(newIndex, item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

If you go through the source code, you'll see that what you are dragging around is a `Bitmap`. The list item is sitting at its original position.

Comment: My onItemMoved() is not getting called even after calling listview.setOnItemMovedListener(this);

Comment: what is this mEntries in the code? I mean an ArrayList or an object that hase defined items of a single row or anything else?

Comment: @HirakChhatbar mEntries is an ArrayList in this scenarios. But, it can be any data structure that you pass to your BaseAdapter or ArrayAdapter.

Answer (score 5):

For others having the same problem - Niek Haarman has answered this question on [GitHub here](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations/issues/268#issuecomment-61364379).

Don't see GitHub going down soon, but as it is good tone to paste the answer too, here it is:

> ```
> @Override
> public long getItemId(int position) {
>     return position;
> }
>
> @Override
> public boolean hasStableIds() {
>     return true;
> }
> ```
>
> `position` is not a stable id here. You need a stable id for the item
>   which does not depend on the position.

Comment: Right! This was the problem for me! My solution: @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return list.get(position).hashCode();
    } where list is the ArrayList that I used

Answer (score 0):

use 
import com.nhaarman.listviewanimations.ArrayAdapter;

instead of
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

that is the reason it doesn't calling onItemMoved

Comment: Yeah you need to do this. And once you do - you don't need the `onItemMoved` and `moveItem` business described in Athena's answer . `onItemMoved` is just a listener to tell you when such an action was completed. The swapping logic happens inside the custom ArrayAdapter.